# Limit network bandwidth on fixed rate for all connections/users

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, bandwidth

I am looking for the commands in Linux to limit the rate of upload/download for all users to the fixed rate.

I have three Linux commands that limit the network rate on OS.

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 10
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 1000kbps ceil 1500kbps 
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 10kbps ceil 20kbps
```

When I try to download from this server with one client the download rate is 20Kbps, but when trying to download with two clients the rate reduces to 9-10Kbps for each client.

Is there any way to keep the rate on 20Kbps or any fixed value for more than one connection/user?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the HTB qdisc, you should create a separate class for every user/connection, for those you want limit the bandwidth.

Typical configuration of class tree:

- root qdisc (HTB, handle 1:0, default class 1:2)

  - root class (HTB, classid 1:1 parent 1:0, rate 100Mbit)

    - default class (HTB, classid 1:2, parent 1:1, rate 50Mbit, ceil 100Mbit)
    - shared class (HTB, classid 1:3, parent 1:1, rate 50Mbit, ceil 100Mbit)

      1. `host1` class (HTB, classid 1:11, parent 1:3, rate 20Kbit)
      2. `host2` class (HTB, classid 1:12, parent 1:3, rate 20Kbit)
      3. `hostN` class (HTB, classid 1:13, parent 1:3, rate 20Kbit)

The tc commands should look like:

```
# remove current configuration if exists
tc q del dev <iface> root || true
tc q del dev <iface> ingress || true

# create the root queue discipline
tc q add dev <iface> root handle 1:0 htb default 3

# attach the root class to the root qdisc
tc c add dev <iface> parent 1:0 classid 1:1 htb rate 100Mbit

# default class
tc c add dev <iface> parent 1:1 classid 1:2 htb rate 50Mbit ceil 100Mbit

# class to limit the hosts
tc c add dev <iface> parent 1:1 classid 1:3 htb rate 50Mbit ceil 100Mbit

# attach classes to limit every host (one class = one host)
tc c add dev <iface> parent 1:3 classid 1:11 htb rate 20Kbit
tc c add dev <iface> parent 1:3 classid 1:12 htb rate 20Kbit
tc c add dev <iface> parent 1:3 classid 1:13 htb rate 20Kbit

# classification of the downstream traffic to hosts
tc f add dev <iface> parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 10 handle 800::1 u32 match ip dst 192.0.2.2 flowid 1:11
tc f add dev <iface> parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 10 handle 800::2 u32 match ip dst 192.0.2.3 flowid 1:12
tc f add dev <iface> parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 10 handle 800::3 u32 match ip dst 192.0.2.4 flowid 1:13
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep the rate for everyone on 20kpbs without defining any classes?

Answer (score 0):

I can't ask Anton Danilov with a comment yet, "If I want to allocate 50% of bandwidth to be available for contention but I want to divide the remaining 50% up amongst users equally, ensuring a guaranteed minimum, how would one go about doing that?"